# Import model from 3dsmax into unity3d with lighting

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, 3d-modelling

I have a model of interior of house developed in 3dsmax. However when I import into unity3d the lights and texture dont get imported. I want to get the same output as i see in 3dsmax. Please help me out here. I export it in .fbx format.

Answer (score 0):

If your textures, height map etc... are in different folder you have to make new material and add these textures to it, after that you can add this material to your 3d model.

for example if you have the same situation

[image: example]

create new material and attach your textures to it.
[image: Material]

and finally attach your material to your 3d model.
[image: Model]

Answer (score 0):

you could try some USD pipeline (Pixar’s Universal Scene Description).

The idea is exactly what you want, exporting/importing scene seamlessly, or close too. [https://fileinfo.com/extension/usd#:~:text=What%20is%20a%20USD%20file%3F%20A%20USD%20file,references%20to%20external%20assets%20included%20in%20the%20scene](https://fileinfo.com/extension/usd#:%7E:text=What%20is%20a%20USD%20file%3F%20A%20USD%20file,references%20to%20external%20assets%20included%20in%20the%20scene).

Where googling a bit you could find latest 3dsmax or plugin that can Export in USD.

Same for latest Unity builds that can import apparently
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.formats.usd.html

I did not test this pipe, but in theory it should help you digging into USD.